# sql query giving some error

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a sql query and it is giving soem error saying "Group" is not used correctly.
I am using one of the sql wraper creted to interact with db2 tables.

Can some one please guide me what is wrong.I can not use PIVOT so tried this.

```
with CTE as
(
select distinct(P.Hfan_id )as HFAN_ID,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'BUSI_WANT_CALL' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as BUSI_WANT_CALL,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILDREN1_DT' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILDREN1_DT,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILDREN2_DT'Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILDREN2_DT,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILDREN3_DT'Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILDREN3_DT,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILDREN4_DT'Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILDREN4_DT,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILDREN5_DT'Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILDREN5_DT,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILD1_RESPONS' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILD1_RESPONS,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILD2_RESPONS' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILD2_RESPONS,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILD3_RESPONS' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILD3_RESPONS,

Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILD4_RESPONS' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILD4_RESPONS,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILD5_RESPONS' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILD5_RESPONS,

Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'CODEPT_SPOUSE_MK' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as CODEPT_SPOUSE_MK,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HL_SUMMERHOUSE_MK' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HL_SUMMERHOUSE_MK, 
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HL_STUDENT_LOAN' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HL_STUDENT_LOAN ,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HL_OTHER_LOAN' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HL_OTHER_LOAN ,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'SHFAN_CPR_ID' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as SHFAN_CPR_ID ,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'SHL_STUDENT_LOAN' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as SHL_STUDENT_LOAN,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'SHL_OTHER_LOAN' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as SHL_OTHER_LOAN, 
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HL_LOANTYPE' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HL_LOANTYPE,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HL_LOAN_AMOUNT' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HL_LOAN_AMOUNT,
Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HL_PROPERTY_TYPE' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HL_PROPERTY_TYPE


Group by P.hfan_id, P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT, P.HFA_PARAM_NV
having
P.hfan_id in
(14835145,
14697134,
14697430,
14694884,
14694999,
14693122,
14693074)
)

Select * from P1,

S.HFAS_EMAIL, 
S.HFAS_PRIV_MOB_NR,
Q.HFAS_ÆGTESTIL_TP, 
R.HFAN_BØRN_HJEM_AN, 
R.HFAN_TO_LÅNTAG_MK

from CTE P1 
inner join hf.HF_ANSØGER_S Q
on P1.hfan_id = Q.hfan_id 
inner join hf.HF_ANSØGNING_S R
on P1.hfan_id = R.hfan_id
inner join hf.HF_ANSØGER1_S S
on P1.hfan_id=S.hfan_id
```

**Error-** "Group" is not used correctly.

Comment: You don't have a `from` clause in the CTE.

Comment: Besides the missing `from`, you are also using both `distinct` and `group by`. This makes very little sense; remove the `distinct` and select the attributes in your `group by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, you are missing the `from` clause in the CTE.  In addition, you should be filtering in a `where` clause not the `having`.  And the `group by` doesn't look write (hint:  `select distinct` is almost never needed in an aggregation query).

So, I think it should look like this:

```
with CTE as (
      select P.Hfan_id,
             . . .
      from p
      where P.hfan_id in (14835145, 14697134, 14697430, 14694884, 14694999, 14693122, 14693074)
      Group by P.hfan_id
     )
```

Comment: I used the code i pasted.the from error is resolved buut still I am getting some duplicate data .Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
select distinct(P.Hfan_id )as HFAN_ID,
...
(THERE SHOULD BE A FROM STATEMENT HERE)
group by P.hfan_id, P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT, P.HFA_PARAM_NV
```

You need to have a FROM between those 2. Try that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use distinct with GROUP BY... and as others said, FROM is missing

Comment: . . Of course you *can* use `select distinct` with `group by`.  It is almost never needed.  (Challenge:  think of a question where `select distinct` in an aggregation query is appropriate ;).

Comment: You are right (as usually) :) I have never used distinct with group by but as you said, it is possible. Ex. select distinct aa, count(*) from table group by aa, bb;

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the columns you are "GROUPing BY" in the SELECT Statement. You need to add P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT to the Select statement as a separate column

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone for your answer.The working solution (just in case):

```
   with CTE as
    (
    select P.Hfan_id as HFAN_ID,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'BUSI_WANT_CALL' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as BUSI_WANT_CALL,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILDREN1_DT' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILDREN1_DT,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILDREN2_DT'Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILDREN2_DT,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILDREN3_DT'Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILDREN3_DT,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILDREN4_DT'Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILDREN4_DT,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILDREN5_DT'Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILDREN5_DT,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILD1_RESPONS' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILD1_RESPONS,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILD2_RESPONS' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILD2_RESPONS,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILD3_RESPONS' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILD3_RESPONS,

    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILD4_RESPONS' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILD4_RESPONS,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HFAN_CHILD5_RESPONS' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HFAN_CHILD5_RESPONS,

    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'CODEPT_SPOUSE_MK' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as CODEPT_SPOUSE_MK,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HL_SUMMERHOUSE_MK' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HL_SUMMERHOUSE_MK, 
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HL_STUDENT_LOAN' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HL_STUDENT_LOAN ,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HL_OTHER_LOAN' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HL_OTHER_LOAN ,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'SHFAN_CPR_ID' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as SHFAN_CPR_ID ,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'SHL_STUDENT_LOAN' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as SHL_STUDENT_LOAN,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'SHL_OTHER_LOAN' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as SHL_OTHER_LOAN, 
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HL_LOANTYPE' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HL_LOANTYPE,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HL_LOAN_AMOUNT' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HL_LOAN_AMOUNT,
    Min(Case P.HFA_PARAM_NV When 'HL_PROPERTY_TYPE' Then P.HFAN_PARAM_TXT End) as HL_PROPERTY_TYPE
    from hf.hf_ANSØGNINGP_S P
    where 
    P.hfan_id in
    (14835145,
    14834519,
    14697430,
    14694884,
    14694999,
    14693122,
    14693074)
    Group by P.hfan_id

    )

    Select P1.*,

    S.HFAS_EMAIL, 
    S.HFAS_PRIV_MOB_NR,
    Q.HFAS_ÆGTESTIL_TP, 
    R.HFAN_BØRN_HJEM_AN, 
    R.HFAN_TO_LÅNTAG_MK

    from CTE P1 
    inner join hf.HF_ANSØGER_S Q
    on P1.hfan_id = Q.hfan_id 
    inner join hf.HF_ANSØGNING_S R
    on P1.hfan_id = R.hfan_id
    inner join hf.HF_ANSØGER1_S S
    on P1.hfan_id=S.hfan_id
```